# Finding an element in an ordered list slicing list into smaller arrays

Tags: python, list, function, search

I'm trying to write a function on python where, given an ordered list 'arr', we want to find an element 'target'. The idea is to take the middle element 'A_m' in the list and compare it with the 'target'. If 'target' < A_m then we know that it will be in the fist A_m elements, if 'target' > A_m, then we know that it will be between A_m and the last element. We can do this until A_m = 'target'. And return the index of this element in the list.

My code is this:

```
 def search(arr, target):
    
    m = len(arr)//2            #midpoint of the length of list
    a_m = arr[m-1]             #mid element of the list use -1 because index starts at 0
    
    if target > a_m:
        arr = arr[0:m]
        
    if target < a_m:
        arr = arr[m:]
        
    if target == a_m:
        return arr.index(a_m)
```

However this doesn't work, what am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it won't return anything when I run it with some list and target value.

Comment: "do this until" describes some kind of repetition, but your code does everything only once. To repeat something there would have to be a loop or recursion.

Comment: Yes because there is only one return statement inside an if statement. If the condition is false, there will be no return value.

Comment: Notice that the re-assignments to *arr* are meaningless because the only comparison is between *target* and *a_m* (which you assign once at the beginning of the function). You're going to need a loop. What you're trying to implement is a binary search (a.k.a. binary chop)

Comment: @OldBill Thank you. I used a while loop and it works.

Comment: It may be worth looking at [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) or [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy-searchsorted) both of which do a binary search to find an insertion point. You can check then check if the value at the insertion point matches your expected value. If you are using numpy arrays the numpy method should be a lot faster as it will all be done in C code. I would expect bisect to perform better as well.